# Невозможно прибавить код знака строки к переменной в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Я боролся с багами в одной программе, которую написал на особом языке, сделанным мной же. Ссылку на его спецификацию давать не буду, а выдам перевод кода на JavaScript, чтобы код был читаемым для программиста:

```
var s = prompt();
var x;
for(var i1 = 0; i1 < s.length; i1++){
    x += s.charCodeAt(i1);
}
console.log(x);
```

В результате на консоль выводится не число (`NaN`). Вот детали борьбы с багами:

```
1. var s = prompt(); // вводим строку, к примеру, `Hello World!`
2. var x; // создаем искомую переменную
3. Расширяем цикл for( i1 < s.length; i1++)
   1. var i1 = 0; // создаем счётчик
      // s.length = 12
   2. Счётчик равен 0. Цикл начинается {
      1. x += s.charCodeAt(i1); // <== БДЫЩ! Вот здесь нашлась ошибка.
```

В конце этого этапа к `x` не прибавляется 72 (что и есть код нулевого знака строки), а получается `NaN`. В `x` тоже попадает `NaN`. Итак, это и есть основная проблема, и я описал всё, что мог, так что...

Вопрос: **Почему в `x` при прибавлении к нему кода знака строки попадает `NaN` и что надо делать**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

начальное значение переменной `x` - *undefined*,

При попытке прибавить к нему число, происходит попытка сконвертировать *undefined* в число в результате получается *NaN*, а любая арифметическая операция с *NaN* - вернет *NaN*

> что надо делать?

Зависит от ожидаемого результата, если нужно найти сумму всех кодов

```
x = 0;
```

если нужно получить строку в которой записаны коды символов

```
x = '';
```